# How to implement siyamed's satellite menu?

Tags: android, menu, android-support-library, satellite

I'm trying to implement siyamed's satellite menu and I'm facing with this popular question all over the stack, but even if I read all the answer, I couldn't make it work so far. Does anyone have other ideas to make id work? Thanks !

Here is the:

**Library:**

https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu

Here is the:

**main_activity.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android.view.ext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@drawable/front"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
            android:text="@string/cd"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:color="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <com.cngcnasaud.orar
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" 
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        sat:satelliteDistance="170dp"
        sat:mainImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        sat:totalSpacingDegree="90"
        sat:closeOnClick="true"
        sat:expandDuration="500"/>





    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/sdb"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         />






</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**The errors are:**

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'satelliteDistance' in package 
     'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'mainImage' in package 'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'closeOnClick' in package 
     'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'expandDuration' in package 
     'android.view.ext'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'totalSpacingDegree' in package 
     'android.view.ext'
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android.view.ext
```

to

```
xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

This should work, worked for me though.

Answer (score 1):

In your main_activity.xml replace this line :

```
 xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android.view.ext
```

with this :

```
 xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/<your_package_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

I think you have renamed the `satellite-menu` library to some other. Remove library and give apply. And again add that library give apply. that will resolved.

Right Click of your project and Click Properties and You can see dialog in that Click Android screen like below screen.

[image]

Click that red marked remove that from right side Remove button and Click Add button select renamed library. Click Apply and give ok that error will resolved,

Hope this will help.,

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your namespace

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

then instead of sat: use app: (i.e. sat:satelliteDistance --> app:satelliteDistance)